# keepassx and Skype Client look like Windows 95 after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, 15.04

A few days ago, I upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04 to 15.04

As far as I can see everything works quite smoothly. However the upgrade deleted my jitsi client (no big deal,configurations weren't touched so I reinstalled it), but what surprised me is that some applications look really ugly now, specifically the Skype client and the Keepassx-Manager look like Win95.

[image]
[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Some applications for Linux, such as Skype, are just adapted so that they can run using Wine. I know for sure that's why Skype looks like that, and I don't know why this seems to be new for you. Skype looks like 2000/95 for me on 14.04.

Comment: You should add a screenshot.

Comment: they definitly changed their look. I'll add some screens to make sure the issue is understood correctly .

Comment: Old, but maybe helpful http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/get-better-looking-qt-applications-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `qt4-qtconfig`

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

Start via terminal

```
qtconfig-qt4
```

or via your app launcher

<kbd>Qt 4 Settings</kbd>

and change the style here

[image]